# crossdomain - Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsonp

I need to call a wordpress page and show the page in a div tag on another webpage not using iframes etc. I have tried many different approaches like jsonp and so on, but i need a good example, keeps getting errors. I have full access to both domains.

Kind regards
Mikael

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

Comment: I have solved it my self. please remember to add the <?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?> to the index.php page and then i used the fantastic script by alexn.org : http://alexn.org/blog/2011/03/24/cross-domain-requests.html

Answer (score 1):

Create an .htaccess on the domain you want to access with this:

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type" Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

Then you can use jQuery .load, for example, to get pages from the other domain.