# Google streetview with data on remote server? (ajax, jsonp)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Have a look at my Google custom streetview player implementation (simplified for testing): http://www.detestserver.de/sameserver/start.html

It works well as long as the player.js and the test.php file (for the data) are on the same server.

Data is still retrieved, but display fails when the test.php file is on another server:
http://www.detestserver.de/differentservers/start.html

Even with "async: false" in the ajax call for the jsonp.

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide more info but on that second server if I go to http://www.detestserver.de/test.php I get an error 500. Check the logs to get the detail of the error.

Comment: Same server files:  http://www.detestserver.de/sameserver
Other server php file: http://usatestserver.com/differentservers

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is cross-domain Ajax. You can try the following:

[crossdomain - Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955998/crossdomain-ajax)

After seeing your debug screen are you trying to retrieve Google tiles directly? I'm not sure about StreetView but with map tiles they take active steps to prevent them being downloaded from third-party applications so it may be that your referrer code is being blocked.

Comment: These screenshots show that the data has been retrieved: http://www.detestserver.de/differentservers/different_servers_1.png and 
http://www.detestserver.de/differentservers/different_servers_2.png

Thats why I do not think is it is a cross-domain problem.

Comment: I just updated my answer to include another possibility now I can see you are getting a 404 error from Google.

Comment: It is not the map tiles. Google Terms of use expressively allow to display map-tiles. We provide the panorama images ourselves.